# CORS issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present, BUT only in some requests - ReactJS + Flask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, cors, fetch

I'm having the known error `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, but by some reason that I didn't figured out yet, because it happens on only one API fetch (get request) which was done exactly the same way on the server side and the client side. When was developing locally, I solved it adding the CORS to the server side, but now I deployed the server Flask to Azure where I added the HTTPS and HTTP address to azure CORS. Why it works with some, and with `getQualityStation` get request fails?

```js
  // Works
  getWaterNeo4jAPI = () => {
    axios.get(API_SERVER_URL + "api/waternode").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;
      if (typeof data !== "undefined") {
        this.setState({ infra: { data: data[0].waternodes } });
        // console.log(data[0]["waternodes"][0].location[0])
      }
    });
  };

 // Works
  getRelNeo4jAPI = () => {
    axios.get(API_SERVER_URL + "api/waternode/relation").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;
      if (typeof data !== "undefined") {
        this.setState({ relations: { data: data } });
      }
    });
  };

  // Works
  getShapefile = () => {
    axios.get(API_SERVER_URL + "api/map/watershed/geojson/").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;
      console.log("receveide shp", data);
      if (typeof data !== "undefined") {
        this.setState({ shapefile: { data: data } });
      }
    });
  };

  // RIP, this 
  getQualityStation = () => {
    axios.get(API_SERVER_URL + "api/water-quality/station").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;
      console.log("receive Station", data[0].station);
      if (typeof data !== "undefined") {
        this.setState({ qualityStation: { data: data[0].station } });
      }
    });
  };
```

The error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://app.azurewebsites.net/api/water-quality/station/' (redirected from 'https://app.azurewebsites.net/api/water-quality/station') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

The server-side (Flask):

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 32 * 1024 * 1024
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})


...

@app.route('/api/waternode/relation', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @app.cache.cached(timeout=10, key_prefix="get_water_rel")
def get_water_rel():
    """ API endpoint to get all relationships with water nodes
           Args:
                no value
            Returns:
                Returns json object that may contain multiple dictionaries representing each relationship
    """
    try:
        resp = ses.run(queries.QUERY_GET_ALL_WATER_REL).data()
    except AttributeError:
        abort(400)

    return return_response(resp)


@app.route('/api/water-quality/station', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @app.cache.cached(timeout=10, key_prefix="get_stations")
def get_stations():
    """ API endpoint to get data of available water stations
            Args:
                no value
            Returns:
                Returns json object that may contain multiple dictionaries representing each station
    """
    try:
        resp = ses.run(queries.QUERY_GET_STATIONS).data()
    except AttributeError:
        abort(400)

    return return_response(resp)
```

---

UPDATE

I changed the Flask endpoint like as mention on the comments, adding the header to the endpoint's response:

```py
@app.route('/api/water-quality/station', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @app.cache.cached(timeout=10, key_prefix="get_stations")
def get_stations():
    """ API endpoint to get data of available water stations
            Args:
                no value
            Returns:
                Returns json object that may contain multiple dictionaries representing each station
    """
    try:
        resp = ses.run(queries.QUERY_GET_STATIONS).data()
    except AttributeError:
        abort(400)

    response = make_response(jsonify(resp))
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.content_type = "application/json"
    print(response)

    return response
```

But unfortunately did worked.

I also tried to add CORS via decorator, but did worked too.

```
@app.route('/api/water-quality/station', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin() # here
def get_stations():
    """ API endpoint to get data of available water stations
            Args:
                no value
            Returns:
                Returns json object that may contain multiple dictionaries representing each station
    """
    try:
        resp = ses.run(queries.QUERY_GET_STATIONS).data()
    except AttributeError:
        abort(400)

    return return_response(resp)
```

**I also tried to use only flask.jsonify but the result was the same**. And the last attempt was adding the header manualy:

```
CORS_HEADER = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'headers': {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}}

def return_response(resp, debug=False):
    if debug:
        print(resp)

    if 'error' in resp:
        return abort(404)

    return json.dumps(resp, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='latin1', ignore_nan=True), 200, CORS_HEADER


...


@app.route('/api/water-quality/station', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @app.cache.cached(timeout=10, key_prefix="get_stations")
def get_stations():
    """ API endpoint to get data of available water stations
            Args:
                no value
            Returns:
                Returns json object that may contain multiple dictionaries representing each station
    """
    try:
        resp = ses.run(queries.QUERY_GET_STATIONS).data()
    except AttributeError:
        abort(400)

    return return_response(resp)
```

Comment: Try adding  the `response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` header before sending the response in that route

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AmilaSenadheera . I tried do add directly the header via axios: ``axios.get(API_SERVER_URL + "api/waterquality/station", {headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}}).`` but no progress.

Comment: No, you need to add it in your python code in `api/water-quality/station` this route function